# Get exe name next to batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have used this batch script to create shortcut of an `.exe` but I want to get the `.exe` name also dynamically. In a folder I have batch file and also one `.exe` file I want to get that `.exe` name dynamically in my batch file.

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Player111.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%CD%\Pacman.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

I want to set `oLink.TargetPath` dynamically. It will be the path where the batch file located along with the `.exe` name. How can I get `Pacman.exe` as mentioned in above code dynamically? Remember, exactly one `.exe` is in the folder.

Comment: err, use `%1`, `%2` ... batch arguments. That's the question?

Comment: what? did u get the question? i want to set dynamically oLink.TargetPath with path and current exe next to the batch file

Comment: `TYPE %SCRIPT%&pause` before `del %SCRIPT%`. Then [edit] your question and provide `oLink.TargetPath` line: what does read currently and what **should be**

Comment: do I understand right? There is (exactly one) exe in the same path as your batchfile and you want to get it's name?

Comment: @Stephan exactly one exe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the full path to the `.exe` located in the parent directory of the batch file, use the following code:

```
for %%F in ("%~dp0*.exe") do set "EXEFILE=%%~fF"
```

(Note: To use the current working directory instead, replace `%~dp0*.exe` by `%CD%\*.exe`.)

Finally, replace the line `echo oLink.TargetPath = "%CD%\Pacman.exe" >> %SCRIPT%` by:

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%EXEFILE%" >> %SCRIPT%
```

---

Here is the full script -- also with some other improvements:

```dos
@echo off

set "SCRIPT=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

for %%F in ("%~dp0*.exe") do set "EXEFILE=%%~fF"

> "%SCRIPT%" (
    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Player111.lnk"
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut^(sLinkFile^)
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "%EXEFILE%"
    echo oLink.Save
)

cscript //NoLogo "%SCRIPT%"
del "%SCRIPT%"
```

Comment: thanks comments explantion will higligh appreciated what to do if there are more than one exe

Comment: Depends on what should be done in such cases: create a link for every `.exe` (so you cannot use a constant `.lnk` name any more), or to chose a certain `.exe` file (so the search criteria need to be defined)...

Answer (score 1):

to get a filename to a variable (assuming there is only one match):

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0*.exe") do set "file=%%a"
echo %file%
```

and later

```
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%file%" >> %SCRIPT%
```

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan, depends on what your directory path is, I guess...